# Random string generation with same pattern

Tags: ruby, random

I want to generate a random string with the pattern:

```
number-number-letter-SPACE-letter-number-number
```

for example `"81b t15"`, `"12a x13"`. How can I generate something like this? I tried generating each char and joining them into one string, but it does not look efficient.

Comment: Could you show code that you tried, and explain what you mean by "does not look efficient" - do you want faster code, better use of Ruby idioms? Also, do the codes need to be secure/unguessable (in which case better to use `SecureRandom` than built-in `rand`)

Comment: You already have a solution? Can you show it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Nums = (0..9).to_a
Ltrs = ("A".."Z").to_a + ("a".."z").to_a
def rand_num; Nums.sample end
def rand_ltr; Ltrs.sample end

"#{rand_num}#{rand_num}#{rand_ltr} #{rand_ltr}#{rand_num}#{rand_num}"
# => "71P v33"
```

Comment: @sawa: I thought posting a similar solution, just for laughs. Indeed, using methods and converting ranges to arrays seem to be very inefficient

Comment: @kimmmo, Sergio I was aware of that but did not take it seriously. I changed the code.

Comment: You can also write as `[*"A".."Z", *"a".."z"]`,, Give Ruby the *headache* :-) +1

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at [randexp gem](https://github.com/benburkert/randexp)

It works like this:

```
> /\d\d\w \w\d\d/.gen
=> "64M c82"
```

Comment: Note to readers: Brian didn't actually give the answer. Sergio Tulentsev did.

Comment: @sawa how did I not give the answer?

Comment: @Brian: you copied the example from the wiki which did not do what was asked.

Comment: @sawa I see what you mean.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's another entry for the competition :D

```
module RandomString
  LETTERS      = (("A".."Z").to_a + ("a".."z").to_a)
  LETTERS_SIZE = LETTERS.size
  SPACE        = " "
  FORMAT       = [:number, :letter, :number, :space, :letter, :number, :number]

  class << self
    def generate
      chars.join
    end

    def generate2
      "#{number}#{letter}#{number} #{letter}#{number}#{number}"
    end

    private

    def chars
      FORMAT.collect{|char_class| send char_class}
    end

    def letter
      LETTERS[rand(LETTERS_SIZE)]
    end

    def number
      rand 10
    end

    def space
      SPACE
    end
  end
end
```

And you use it like:

```
50.times { puts RandomString.generate }
```

Out of curiosity, I made a benchmark of all the solutions presented here. Here are the results:

**JRuby:**

```
       user     system      total        real
kimmmo   1.490000   0.000000   1.490000 (  0.990000)
kimmmo2  0.600000   0.010000   0.610000 (  0.479000)
sawa     0.960000   0.040000   1.000000 (  0.533000)
hp4k     2.050000   0.230000   2.280000 (  1.234000)
brian   17.700000   0.170000  17.870000 ( 14.867000)
```

**MRI 2.0**

```
       user     system      total        real
kimmmo   0.900000   0.000000   0.900000 (  0.908601)
kimmmo2  0.410000   0.000000   0.410000 (  0.406443)
sawa     0.570000   0.000000   0.570000 (  0.568935)
hp4k     4.940000   0.000000   4.940000 (  4.945404)
brian   25.860000   0.010000  25.870000 ( 25.870011)
```

Comment: Nothing can beat Brian's solution in terms of conciseness :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
(0..9).to_a.sample(2).join + ('a'..'z').to_a.sample + " " + ('a'..'z').to_a.sample + (0..9).to_a.sample(2).join
```